# Facebook PHP SDK show page feed, and link to post

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

With this code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '-',
    'secret' => '-',
));

$pageFeed = $facebook->api(PAGE ID . '/feed')
```

I get the id, the message, the story, and the created_time + pagination. I want to get the post url too, and if image is shared, the image url to show the image. How can I get that datas from the Page's wall?

Answer (score -1):

See the Choosing fields pat of the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields